# Maven dependency scopes for multi-module project

Tags: java, maven

I am on initial stage of a java project (jsp/servlet project with maven). It is a multi-module project. I am using maven.
For now say there are 3 modules.

Model, controller, and web module.
`model` needs mysql lib
`controller` uses `model`, extends and uses model's classes
`web` needs `controller` and `model` both modules.

I have added mysql to model's dependency, model is added to `controller` module's dependency, and `controller` is added to `web` module's depencency. (And do I need to add `model` module to dependency of `web` module? )

How can/should I configure scopes of dependencies of these modules?

**EDIT: Structure**

```
Root
 |
 |---Model  *dependencies:mysqllib/compile*
 |
 |---Controller *dependencies:Model/compile*
 |
 |---Web  *dependencies:Controller/compile*
```

All are set to `complie` scope.
I have a .jsp file inside web module (which is default jsp), 
this jsp calls static method `Account.getAccount()` of a class which is inside controller module.

**JSP code**

```
<%=xy.controller.Account.getAccount()%>
```

while opening above jsp file in browser I get below exception in browser

**Error stack**

```
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 8 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
xy.controller.AccountH cannot be resolved to a type
5:     <title></title>
6:   </head>
7:   <body>
8:                        <%=xy.controller.Account.getAccount()%>
9:   </body>
10: </html>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:469)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

**Dependencies in pom files**
- controller - pom

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>xy</groupId>
            <artifactId>model</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

- web - pom

> ```
> <dependency>
>             <groupId>xy</groupId>
>             <artifactId>controller</artifactId>
>             <version>0.0.1</version>
>             <scope>compile</scope>
>         </dependency>
> ```

Comment: Are you sure your problems are the dependencies? The controller needs a packaging of 'jar' and the web a packaging of 'war' and you have to either first `mvn install` controller before `mvn package`ing web, or have a parent pom with packaging 'pom' that lists both as modules. Also, I assume you deployed the war file built by the 'package' command, and you do not have any 'provided' scopes in your war? Checking your WEB-INF/lib inside the war if the libs are there might also be helpful...

Comment: In case you are testing the project in Eclipse with m2e, note that old m2e versions had a bug to not correctly configure deployment assembly section of war projects (not sure if fixed in any released version yet). In that case, try to remove the projects from Eclipse, build "classic" Eclipse config files with `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and use those classic projects, or fix up the dpeloyment assembly section in the project configuration manually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment of @mihi

> Are you sure your problems are the dependencies? The controller needs
>   a packaging of 'jar' and the web a packaging of 'war' and you have to
>   either first mvn install controller before mvn packageing web, or have
>   a parent pom with packaging 'pom' that lists both as modules. Also, I
>   assume you deployed the war file built by the 'package' command, and
>   you do not have any 'provided' scopes in your war? Checking your
>   WEB-INF/lib inside the war if the libs are there might also be
>   helpful...

Adding packaging of 'war' and adding parent pom with packaging of 'pom' resolved the problem.
Thanks @mihi.

Answer (score 3):

All the dependencies in current project and its ancestors are available to a project.

> ```
> Root  *dependencies:libA*
>  |
>  |---Model  *dependencies:mysqllib*
>  |
>  |---Controller *dependencies:Model*
>  |
>  |---Web  *dependencies:Model,Controller*
> ```

To answer your question: *yes*, you will need to explicitly add Model to Web module's dependency list, if you have a structure like above. Note that `libA` is accessible to all 3 modules but `mysqllib` is available only to Model.

You can play around with parent-child relationship to decide how you want to structure your project.

Comment: Thanks, Structure is same as you have explained. What should I keep scopes for them? Please explain

Comment: Dependency scopes tell the scope of the dependency. when and for how long(think scope), it will be needed. It does nothing special in multi module project. If a project inherits the dependency from parent, it will have the same scope as in parent's pom.

Comment: Yes but what scopes will you assign to above modules in above case?

Comment: I advise using the _default_ scope (compile) unless you have a specific requirement for any other scope. Look [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

Comment: Please see my edit in question. I have set scopes of all dependencies to `compile`, but still what happens is - when I run the project and when I try to access its default jsp file in browser, it throws an error `ClassNotFoundException`, for the class which belongs to `controller` module, and is used in jsp file. I am new, I can't understand the problem.

Comment: @Pratik without a stacktrace its hard to say.

Comment: please see updates in question, I have provided code and error stack.